# Want to install Ubuntu Mate but need advice on hardware issues

Tags: hard-drive, mate

First attempt at install returned errors related to HDD. I wiped the drive using DBAN planning to replace the HDD. When attempting Ubuntu install after HDD wipe I received the following errors:

```
[ 0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: plesae update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)
[ 0.32000] [mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ae00000040110a
[ 0.32000] [mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ABBR ffb07640 MISC 38a0000006
[ 0.32000] [mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:40651 TIME 1537996692 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 17 0
```

Need to know if I have more than HDD issues here before replacing HDD